# Squid not work under HTTPS made by GKE Ingress, but built Squid' Docker image work normally when run on Compute Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, squid

■ In my case, HTTPS is required for Squid proxy, so I'm using GKE Ingress on Google Cloud for making HTTPS connection.

My bult Docker image can work as a proxy function on a VM(Compute Engine) or Service of TCP Load Balancer without any problems, but it does not function on GKE Ingress.

▼ I'm using sources as below (I don't know why, but I must use 4. and 5. to pass healthy checking on GKE Ingress)

1. Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu/squid

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt install -y nginx supervisor curl

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

COPY squid/squid.conf /etc/squid/squid.conf
COPY index.html /var/www/html
COPY health.html /var/www/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 8080 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/supervisord" ]
CMD [ "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

2. GKE Ingress(squid6-deployment.yaml)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: squid6
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: squid6-v01
  namespace: squid6
  labels:
    app: squid6
    env: v01
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: squid6
      env: v01
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: squid6
        env: v01
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: asia-northeast1-docker.pkg.dev/dev-project-01/dev-img-squid6/squid6:{{SHORT_SHA}}
        name: squid6
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 1024Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 512Mi
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: squid6
  name: squid6
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "dev-ca-proxy-example-com"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "dev-ip-squid6-01"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: proxy.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: squid6
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  namespace: squid6
  name: dev-backend-k8s
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 30
    timeoutSec: 5
    healthyThreshold: 1
    unhealthyThreshold: 2
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /health.html
    port: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  namespace: squid6
  name: squid6
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "dev-backend-k8s"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "http"
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30081
  selector:
    app: squid6
    env: v01
```

3. squid.conf

```
http_port 8080

# local src
acl localnet src 192.168.0.1-192.168.255.255
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/24     # Public subnet CIDR
acl localnet src 10.144.128.0/17 # Pod IPv4 address range
acl localnet src 34.119.224.0/20 # IPv4 service range
acl localnet src 130.211.0.0/22  # Google Healthy Checking
acl localnet src 35.191.0.0/16   # Google Healthy Checking

http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet

acl loadBalanerlIP src 34.110.152.xxx # HTTPS Load Balancer IP
http_access allow loadBalanerlIP
```

4. nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

5. supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
user=root
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=info
nodaemon=true

[program:squid]
command=/usr/sbin/squid -N -f /etc/squid/squid.conf
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
autorestart=true

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
autorestart=true
```

▼ Some figure about setup Squid Proxy

1. I can view Squid page via HTTPS normally before set it as proxy server on Windows.
   [Can view Squid page normally via HTTPS URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGhRV.png)
2. Proxy setting on Windows 11
   [Proxy setting on Windows 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD1yJ.png)
3. But, I cannot view any pages after setting up Proxy Server.
   [I cannot view any pages after setting up Proxy Server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsAeu.png)

★I've been using many days to researched, but I can't found solution to fix this problem.
So, could someone give me guidance to fix this hard problem?